# How do I load VLAN database between switches (CISCO 2960)?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-ios, vtp

I glad for any help on  this topic

--

netanel

Comment: Does [this link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus7000/sw/layer2/config/cisco_nexus7000_layer2switching_config_guide_8x/config_mvrp.pdf) help?

Comment: Copy the vlan.dat file from src switch to the dst switch, and reload without any "write". VTP is a cisco proprietary method of sync'ing vlan data across a domain -- it's ancient, has no security, and creates more headaches than it helps. (you still have to go to each member switch to assign ports)

Comment: @Ricky There is security, it’s just really poor.  But yeah, VTP should be left in transparent mode and never messed with if it can be avoided.